# Windows 8 Licence Key won't work

Tags: windows-8, license-key

I know this is a question asked a lot but I am not finding the answer I need on Google.  I recently had to purchase a Windows 8 re-install disk online which worked fine but it is now asking me to put in the licence key before it expires in 30 day, I put in my previous key and it will not recognize it. To purchase the key is over 100 and I think that is very expensive considering my laptop had a Windows 8 OS when I purchased it from the store.  Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You have an OEM key, it won't work with retail version of Windows 8.

Comment: So does that mean I have to purchase a new key???

Comment: To use a regular non-OEM CD/DVD you need a regular key. To use an OEM CD/DVD you need an OEM key. Either get the right disc, or buy a matching key.

Comment: Did your device come with Windows 8 preinstalled? If so, Windows should automatically detect the embedded license and use it.

Comment: Yes it did, and I downloaded a program called Belarc to detect the licence key but the 25 digit key it showed does not work.